# Can we use wildcards in Visual Studio's condition debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'd like to break when `val = "%VALUE"`, where "%" is any character, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use something like that; rather when you set your conditional breakpoint you'll need to use `val.EndsWith("VALUE");` which is the equivalent of the pattern `"%VALUE"`. Alternatively, you could use [Regex.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx) for more complex patterns. [Regex.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx) basically, returns a boolean indicating true if the regular expression finds a match; otherwise, false.

---

if you're interested, `vb.net` does have a similar pattern matching mechanism i.e you could create a conditional breakpoint with the pattern:

```
val Like "*VALUE"
```

to match *zero or more* characters followed by `"VALUE"` or:

```
val Like "?VALUE"
```

to match *any single* character followed by `"VALUE"`.